# Bundled Javascript, how do I inspect that bundles have loaded correctly on the browser, and check the contents

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

I am working on Bundling js files using .NET 4.5 bundling `System.Web.Optimization;` on WebForms. I have managed to add files to `BundleTable` successfully,
[image]

however they don't seem to appear on web page itself. I am able to see bundle specified in Sources Tab on Google Chrome but it is empty, and scripts are failing to load.

[image]

I must be missing something here, **how do I inspect that bundles have loaded correctly on the browser, and check the contents.**

Not that I think it matters, but to prevent avalanche of downvotes.

**Global.ascx**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
namespace OnTheMoveOffline.Framework.App_Start
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/development").Include("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/*.js"));
            var resolver = new BundleResolver(bundles);
            List<string> cont = resolver.GetBundleContents("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/development").ToList();
            Debugger.Break(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Master**

```
 <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/development") %>
```

Comment: Does your code work? If so, your scripts bundled correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't you render the bundle using `Render("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/development")`?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Indeed, could you please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you are using the same name to render the bundle than you used when it was registered, `~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/development` in this case.

So if the bundle is registered like this:

```
new ScriptBundle("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/development")
```

You should render it like this:

```
System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/development")
```